# WCF service which takes files as string

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service which takes files as string and will read the file using below: when i am trying to consume WCF service on dev server issue is it is giving an error `couldn't locate part of the file path`. I have my file at desktop.

Please somebody help me resolve the issue. It's working when I consume web service which is local.

```
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload the files from the client or files are already on the server?

Comment: I am trying to upload a file from client.

Comment: I am trying to Send a file from client. I am sending a file as a string.This WCF service takes file as a string and try to read the content using    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)

Comment: But `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes` accepts a file **path** as an argument, not a string. So it tries to read file content from a filesystem. What do you mean by "*I am sending a file as a string*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts **path** as a parameter.

That **path is only available on the client**. It's not available on the server.
Your app is working locally because in that case client and server are essentially the **same machine**, so they both can access the file. 
But, that's not the case when server is on a different machine.

You need to modify your code to read the file on the client
and pass the bytes[] to the service method

Comment: Thank you !!  now there is another problem my web service is consumed by the cold fusion so they need the code to read the file and pass the bytes[] but i have no idea how to do that, so that's the reason i was trying to path as a parameter. so is there any other way to temp save documents to a folder on a Web server and read from there.

Comment: @pran, technically, you can store the byte[] on the server using `File.WriteAllBytes`. But, your service will need write permissions on the server machine.

Comment: so is there any other way to temp save documents to a folder on a Web server and read from there